# Best method to write objects to a text file

Tags: java, serialization, file-handling, fileinputstream, printwriter

I want to know what would be the best way to save objects to a file ? Saving in the sense, the objects need to be appended. 
When i searched the internet i found that printwriter saves an object in the format of it's toString method, but then if it saves an object to a file in the toString format , how can the programer use it to access an instance in an object. 
What i mean is, if i save a student object to a text file using printwriter(The object has a name, id and age) , how can i use it in the future to compare the age of one student with another student's age / search by id , etc. 
Since the object is saved as a string , it can only be read as a string so how can i access the instances of an object?

The other method i found out is serialization. Serialization looks like it does the job but then i found out that it cannot append objects to a file , because it's stream header keeps on overriding. Is there a method to append objects to a file using serialization ?

Currently these are the only 2 methods i found out for writing objects , but it seems i cannot use any of these methods since when saved using printwriter , it will be read as a string and if i use serialization i can store only one record.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: have you looked into JSON?

Comment: You should try `HIBERNATE`.

Comment: @VimalBera For a text file? Not the best idea, necessarily

Comment: Ill check both the ways :)

Comment: Have you seen ObjectMapper?

Comment: @hexafraction I think Shehan wants to save the value of object for future use. So saving object's state in db is probably helpful.

Comment: @VimalBera Yes, but a RDBMS is not a text fime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[JAXB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Architecture_for_XML_Binding) will be great choice for you, as I see from your problem description. [Here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/jaxb-hello-world-example/) is a simple example to start with.

JAXB is a part of standard JDK since 1.6, so you don't need any additional libraries.
Also is supports collections serialization so you can easily implement your "append" task.

Answer (score 1):

What could be a good idea (in my opinion at least) is to use [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/) to serialize entire objects to file as XML. Using that library you could serialize entire objects to store them and then use that same library to automatically convert the XML back to the objects so that you can compare them.

Also, saving stuff to File as XML will allow other languages to be able to process the same file.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use `FileOutputStream` instead of PrintWriter and simply write the data to a file in append mode? `FileOutputStream` does have a append mode constructor.

- [Java Serialization example](http://javapapers.com/core-java/java-serialization/)
- [FileOutputStream Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html)

Answer (score 1):

How about you override *writeStreamHeader* and reset?

```
ObjectOutputStream ooStream = null;
try{
    ooStream = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("object-writer"));
    ooStream.writeObject(new ObjectWriter());
} catch(Exception ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if(ooStream != null){
        try {
            ooStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

ObjectOutputStream ooStream2 = null;

try{
   ooStream2  = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("object-writer", true)) {
        @Override
        public void writeStreamHeader() throws IOException {
            reset();
        }
    };
    ooStream2.writeObject(new ObjectWriter());
} catch(Exception ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if(ooStream2 != null){
        try {
            ooStream2.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

ObjectInputStream oiStream = null;
try {
    oiStream = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("object-writer"));
    System.out.println(oiStream.readObject());
    System.out.println(oiStream.readObject());
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if(oiStream != null){
        try {
            oiStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```